# Highlighting the same variables in Jupyter Python

Tags: python, jupyter

How to make lightening/emphasis of same varibles when double klick on one of them, like it happens in R

[image]

Comment: Does this give instructions for what you need? https://medium.com/@grayangelo686/debugging-tips-variable-inspector-and-highlight-selected-word-788c9f19ef3e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit > nbextensions config > Highlight Selected Cells + Variable Inspector (instructions lifted from [here](https://medium.com/@grayangelo686/debugging-tips-variable-inspector-and-highlight-selected-word-788c9f19ef3e))

Comment: thank you very much!